# Insert multiple value taken from table 1 into table 2 using PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

I try to get all the value from table 1 then push them in an array. Then I insert the array into table 2, but I got the error said that: *"Illegal string offset 'name' ","Illegal string offset 'lat' ", "Illegal string offset 'lng' "*
I have searched for this error and try to fix it, but I can't. Can anybody help me with this?
Here is my code:

```
$query = "DELETE FROM gpsdata";
    $query_input = "SELECT name, lat, lng FROM gpsdata";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query_input);
    while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        if (is_array($data)) {
            $sql = array();
            foreach ($data as $row) {
                $sql[] = '(' . $row['name'] . ', ' . $row['lat'] . ', ' . $row['lng'] . ')';
            };
            $query2 = "INSERT INTO gpsdata_backup (name, lat, lng) VALUES ' . implode(',', $sql)'";
            $result_insert = mysqli_query($connect, $query2);
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go.  The illegal `offset error` is coming because you have an unnecessary `inner foreach loop` due to which the values were not found in your `$row` array. That is not required

```
// Array declaration to be on top
$sql = array();
$query_input = "SELECT name, lat, lng FROM gpsdata";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query_input);

while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    if (is_array($data)) {

        // Enclose string values in quotes
        $sql[] = '("' . $data['name'] . '", "' . $data['lat'] . '", "' . $data['lng'] . '")';
        
   }
} 

// Final insert should not be inside the loop 
$query2 = "INSERT INTO gpsdata_backup (name, lat, lng) VALUES ".implode(",",$sql);
$result_insert = mysqli_query($connect, $query2);
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are not performing any tasks on the data why not do the entire operation in mysql by inserting directly with a select?

```
insert into `gpsdata_backup` ( `name`, `lat`, `lng` )
    select `name`, `lat`, `lng` from `gpsdata`;
```

ie:

```
$sql='insert into `gpsdata_backup` ( `name`, `lat`, `lng` )
    select `name`, `lat`, `lng` from `gpsdata`';
    
$result=$connect->query( $sql );
```

Comment: Oh, thank you. I have also thought about this solution. But since I have just added some constrain condition that interacts with the data, I took from table 1, so I have to use *Chilarai* solution. But anyway, thank you for your help @Professor Abronsius

Comment: when you say `"I have just added some constrain(t) condition"` - please clarify! The above query can be tweaked to use a `where` clause if that is what you mean...
@hainam - you are welcome!